# Migrating the Kubernetes cluster from one DC to Another DC which involves IP change

Tags: kubernetes, migration

We are planning to Migrate the 3 node kubernetes cluster ( 1 Master , 2 Worker nodes) from one Esxi cluster to another Esxi cluster which involves the IP change.
Is there any best practice to perform the reconfiguration with new IP address.
please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: How was the cluster setup? Where is etcd? Do you have any HA?

Comment: It is a 3 node Cluster all are in same DC.
ETCD are resides in master Kubernetes node.
No HA configured.

Comment: How was it configured and how did you installed the cluster?